# Python: how to remove leading zeros after string in pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
df
     id
0   IT030
1   IT4
2   IT022
3   BE34
```

I would like to remove all the `zeros` after the characters and have this

```
df
     id
0   IT30
1   IT4
2   IT22
3   BE34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
# if 0s after a non digit, remove them
df['id'] = df['id'].str.replace(r'(\D)0+', r'\1', regex=True)
```

or:

```
# if 0s between a non digit and a digit, remove them
df['id'] = df['id'].str.replace(r'(\D)0+(\d+)', r'\1\2', regex=True)
```

output (as new column `id2` for clarity):

```
      id   id2
0  IT030  IT30
1    IT4   IT4
2  IT022  IT22
3   BE34  BE34
```